# Feature-request: Allow question-poster to reward the bounty based on a survey to users

Tags: feature-request

What if I ask a question, but then it  draws many answers which I can't figure out? Maybe the answers are too expert for me, I'm simply undecided, or perhaps I am stuck in emergency and cannot get to the question for lack of time.

This is akin to the "Ask the Audience" feature of game show called "Who Wants to Be a Millionaire?".

By default, the system breaks up the bounty. But why not allow the user to 
reward the bounty based on a survey to users? Just a simple survey, not fancy:

[image: Survey Sample]

This can be restricted, so that only certain question can be allowed to put a survey. For example, if a question goes viral and attracts many answers.

What do you all think?

Comment: Cue the complaints, the survey chose me but the OP chose the other answer.

Comment: First-World-Problem I guess :\

Comment: If *you* are incapable of deciding on the answer which *works best for you*. who can?  If there is a good answer you don't understand but gets UpVotes, those are its own reward.

Answer (score 18):

**This functionality already exists.** People can vote for which answer they think is the best by clicking on one of these:

[image]

It's then up to you whether or not to pick the highest voted answer, or the answer that best helped you solve your problem, and award the bounty to them.

*(By the way, you don't have to award the bounty to the selected answer.)*

If you choose not to award a bounty manually, [the system will automatically give half the bounty to the highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).<sup><sup>†</sup></sup>

<sup><sup>†</sup> *Answer must have been created after the bounty started and have a minimum score of 2.*</sup>

Answer (score 7):

> By default, the system breaks up the bounty

By default, [the bounty is split in half and awarded to whomever received the most upvotes (minimum 2)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/175248) during its run.  This is fair, since if a user offers a bounty of 500 reputation, but no answer is chosen by the offerer, the community can weigh in with their votes.

This system would be incredibly intrusive, because:

- Like OPs, other answers may not be able to gauge the correctness or feasibility of an answer.
- There would be  intense bickering about why someone didn't get selected via the straw poll.
- Some questions may not have the eyeballs looking at them often enough to get enough traffic to *warrant* the poll in the first place.